# UIAlertView deprecated Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to change the following code to the UIAlertController but I get an error saying "Non-invocable member 'UIAlertController' cannot be used like a method"

This is the original code in AppDelegate.cs

```
private void remoteNotificationPayload(NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        var aps_d = userInfo["aps"] as NSDictionary;
        var alert_d = aps_d["alert"] as NSDictionary;
        var body = alert_d["body"] as NSString;
        var title = alert_d["title"] as NSString;

        this.showAlert(title, body);
    }

private void showAlert(string title, string message)
{
  var alert = new UIAlertView(title ?? "Title", message ?? "Message", null, "Cancel", "OK");
  alert.Show();
}
```

I tried this that is where I get the error:

```
private void showAlert(string title, string message)
{
 var okCancelAlertController = UIAlertController(title ?? "Title", message ?? "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

 okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert => Console.WriteLine("Okay was clicked")));

 okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, alert => Console.WriteLine("Cancel was clicked")));
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(okCancelAlertController, true, null);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the static `Create` method on UIAlertController:

```
var okCancelAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I forgot to Create.